# How to prepopulate USStateField in ManytoManyField?

Tags: django

```
territories = models.ManyToManyField(USStateField)
```

First parameter to ManyToManyField must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'

someone can help me how to put the USStateField values inside the ManyToManyField?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

`USStateField` is part of `django.forms`; while a `ManyToManyField` if part of `django.models`: things from `django.forms` cannot be used in model definitions.

The solution is to create a separate model that contains all these states, or use a `CharField` with a list of [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) available for them.

The implementation with the `ManytoManyField` could look like this:

```
class USState(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
        # ... and so on
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    territories = models.ManyToManyField(USState)
```

Assuming you've already created the `USState` instances, you can add them to `MyModel` as follows:

```
m = MyModel()
m.territories.add(USState.objects.get(name="AL"))
m.save()
```

More examples can be found in the Django docs, like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields).

Comment: jro, i want to ask another question. you're answer can be a manytomanyfield or not? it is because i want to have multiselection USStateField.

Comment: can you give me some code of this sir? i really need it. USStateField in ManyToManyField. Thanks! :D

Comment: in your code, is this like you should add some USState first then it will populated in the manytomany field because i want to have them automatically in the manytomanyfield.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "populating the manytomany field", but you can have data available by default by [providing the data via fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Answer (score 0):

To build on jro's answer, I used localflavors.us.models.USStateField to create a simple USState model:

```
from django.db import models

from localflavor.us.models import USStateField


class USState(models.Model):
    name = USStateField()
```

And then modified the initial migration to automatically insert all the states from the localflavors choices:

```
from django.db import models, migrations

import localflavor.us.models
from localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES


def add_states(apps, schema_editor):
    USState = apps.get_model("geography", "USState")
    for state in STATE_CHOICES:
        USState.objects.create(name=state[0])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='USState',
            ...
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(add_states)
    ]
```